# javascript if checkbox is checked, href to ?page2, if at ?page2: keep cb checked, when unchecked, href to ?page1

Tags: php, javascript, get, href, window.location

Im totally new to javascript and i have no clue how to get this to work... I modified the code a little, but note that line 6 makes no sense. That is the main reason for this post.

```
<script>
function checkReloading() {
    if (window.location.href.split=="?showpastdate") {
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked=true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked=false;
    }
}

function toggleAutoRefresh(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        window.location.replace("?showpastdate");
    } else {
        window.location.replace("");
    }
}
window.onload=checkReloading;
</script>
```

Ok i think this is pretty readable.

First of all window.location.href.split doesn't work because I have to give in the full path. But how can I make this dynamic, so it can be used on more websites? Everywhere I see: `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;` but how do I implement this line of code for dynamic webpages? Can someone give me an example?

What I want to achieve with this code is:
When showpastdate is checked, href to `?showpastdate`, when at `?showpastdate` stay checked so i can use php `$_GET` on `?showpastdate`. This works (when i use static full url). But than...

How do I have to modify this code so that the checkbox remains checked at `?showpastdate` untill clicked again, than url goes back to original .php state or other GET var?

Sorry for asking for code writing, but I bet some of u can write this simple lines in 2 minutes while I'm surfing around for 8 hours. Not about to learn javascript, but this really would be a nice option for my program to toggle item showing past date ON/OFF, nicer than having 2 checkboxes, 1 for ON and 1 for OFF :x EDIT: + a submit button @(O _o)@

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got it.

```
<script>
function toggleAutoRefresh(cb) {
    if (~window.location.href.indexOf("?hidepastdate") == 0){
        window.location.replace("?hidepastdate");
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked == true;
    }
    if (~window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate") == 0){
        window.location.replace("?showpastdate");
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked == true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Now the URL gets toggled every time at clicking and PHP does the CSS display work.

Thanks for the effort and for pointing me to the right direction, Cerbrus! Saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 1):

`.split()` is a function you can execute on a string object, to split it up in pieces, depending on a parameter provided:
`"abcdefg|hijklmnop|qrstuvw".split('|')`
would result in a array like this:
`["abcdefg","hijklmnop","qrstuvw"]`

Now, I am guessing you have added a "?showpastdate" parameter to the url, to change a checkbox's "checked" status.
The easiest way to do that would be:

```
document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = (~window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate"))
```

This part: `window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate")` Searches the href for
`"?showpastdate"`
If the string has been found, it will return a index. if not, it will return -1.
The squiggly in front of it is to convert the -1 or 0 (or higher) to a true / false.

I'm not quite sure what the `toggleAutoRefresh()` is supposed to do, though

## Edit 1

Ah, for the `toggleAutoRefresh()`, just add this:

```
if (cb.checked) {
    window.location.href.replace("?showpastdate","");
}
```

instead of that `if-else` block you have there.
The `.replace()` function works on a string the same way `.split()` does. It takes 2 arguments: What to look for, and what to replace it with.
So, for example:

```
var someString = "words and stuff"
var result = someString.replace(" ","_");
//result will be "words_and_stuff"
```

## Edit 2

These functions should work:

```
function checkReloading() {
    document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = (~window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate"))
}

function toggleAutoRefresh(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        window.location.href.replace("?showpastdate","");
    }else{
        window.location.href += "?showpastdate";
    }
}
```

Where are you calling toggleAutoRefresh() from?

## Edit 3

What I can conclude from your last comment, is that you want to do something like this:

```
// If a checkbox named "cb" is checked, and the url contains "?showpastedate"
if ((cb.checked) && ~window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate")) { 
    //Uncheck the checkbox and remove the "?showpastedate" from the url
    document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = false;
    window.location.href.replace("?showpastdate","");
} else {
    // Else, check the checkbox and add the "?showpastedate" to the url
    document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = true;
    window.location.href += "?showpastdate";
}
```

Note the use of the "~" in front of the `indexOf`.
If `string.indexOf("text")` finds `"text"` at the beginning of a string, like it would in `"tekstbooks bla bla bla"`, it returns 0. First index, starting count at 0.

This zero is interpreted as a `false`, when implicitly casting it to a boolean. So, if the `indexOf` were to find a result at the first index, it should (In this situation) return `true` to indicate a string has been found. That's why we apply the [Bitwise NOT](http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/) `~` to the results of `indexOf`. `-1`, `indexOf`'s "Not found" value returns false, and all other results return true.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleAutoRefresh(this);" id="showpastdate">

Comment: So, you want to add `"?showpastdate"` to the url again when checking the checkbox?
editing the code a little...

Comment: yes, when checked, href to .php?showpastdate. When clicked again, href to .php or .php?hidepastdate. Through $_GET I determine which query will be runned, depending on the ?var.

Comment: if (cb.checked) && window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate")) {
document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked=false;
window.location.replace("?showpastdate");

if (cb.unchecked) && window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate")) {
document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked=false;
window.location.replace("?hidepastdate");

Something like this would work, although I rather had a button saying Show, which can be checked to show and unchecked to unshow, but this way i can make Show/Hide toggle out of it.

I think this is the logic some way, but im not familiar with the syntax :(

Comment: I added a new answer for a better explaination

Answer (score 0):

[URL Change Event - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981351/url-change-event-javascript)

http://help.dottoro.com/ljgggdjt.php

I think you could also use the onchange() javascript event.

Comment: Can't use the hash since its working client side. I need to href it to a ?var so I can use $_GET method to determine which mysql query the server has to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain a little bit more.

I have a JQuery datatable, and through CSS I have different `<tr classes>`. Depending on the information stored in the database, these `<tr>` get a different class, thus a different color in the datatable.

Now for one `<tr class>` I'd like to give the user the option to hide/show. I was thinking to do this with a checkbox, and the javascript would parse an url when checked, and remove it when unchecked again. This URL can be used for php to run different queries, if `$_GET['parsedurl']`: query to show all tables, elseif `$_GET['empty']`: query for not showing that 1 information.

But this is the worst way to do it. I need to find something to toggle the `display: none` on or off of the table class, since this is working client-side.

So Im now thinking to keep the parsing of the javascript in an URL and depending on the URL, I run the .php GET to echo out `<tr style: display: none>` or just simply `<tr>`

Therefore I need some javascript which does this:

- If checkbox is checked, redirect to projectlist.php?showpastdate
- When URL = projectlist.php?showpastdate, make checkbox checked.
- When URL = projectlist.php?showpastdate and checkbox gets unchecked, redirect to projectlist.php, where the checkbox is unchecked.

I think these triggers are the best options?

With .PHP I'll do:

```
if (isset($_GET['showpastdate']))
{
<tr style: display: none>
}
else
{
<tr>
}
```

Maybe someone has an even better solution? I'd like to hear!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The javascript I now have is:

```
<script>
function toggleAutoRefresh(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        window.location.replace("?showpastdate");
    }
        // If a checkbox named "cb" is checked, and the url contains "?showpastedate"
    if ((cb.checked) && !~window.location.href.indexOf("?showpastdate")) { 
        //Uncheck the checkbox and remove the "?showpastedate" from the url
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = false;
        window.location.href.replace("?showpastdate","");
    } else {
        // Else, check the checkbox and add the "?showpastedate" to the url
        document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = true;
        window.location.href += "?showpastdate";
    }   
}
</script>
```

After checking the checkbox, it goes to the page projectlist.php?showpastdate and gets unchecked there. When checking again, it goes to projectlist.php?showpastdate?showpastdate. It should remove the ?showpastdate, not add another.

This is could do with PHP too, but I really don´t like a submit button for this checkbox. Just check and execute.

Comment: You forgot the `,""` in your first `if`, in the last code block.
It should be:
`window.location.href.replace("?showpastdate","");`

Comment: Actually, if the page loads with the checkbox checked ("?showpastdate" being in the url), it shouldn't do anything, right? (Aside from keeping the checkbox checked)
In that case, remove the entire `if` block.

Comment: If I place "" beside (1st if block), doesn't change anything. If I remove the (1st) if block, can't even check the checkbox, guess cos it refreshes

Comment: I noticed a mistake in my code. The exclamation mark (!) in the 2nd `if` block, shouldn't be there. Are you calling the toggleAutoRefresh function when you click the checkbox called cb? If that's so, remove the `document.getElementById("showpastdate").checked = true/false` lines.

Comment: haha we're closer :P now it stays at ?showpastdate, but doesn't remove it when checked again (it gets unchecked again automaticly when redirected but thats ok)